# How to keep a website embedded when a link is clicked

Tags: iframe, embed

I'm trying to build a site that acts as an overlay (sort-of like an addon) to a different site.
So i have site A in which i want to embed site B (which is not mine). I tried using a iframe, but opening a link through the iframe will result in opening a new tab of site B.

So my question is how can i embed site B, with site B working like normal, while keeping it embedded in site A.

Thanks!